# What the maximum number of monitors a FirePro W5100 can drive:

Tags: windows, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I've been trying to setup a monitor wall and would like to know if the AMD FirePro W5100 would be able to drive 12 monitors at the same time. The manufacturer states that it has 4 DisplayPort 1.2a. So by using a 1-to-3 DisplayPort Hub on each one of the output ports, would I be able to drive 12 monitors at a resolution of 1440x900 or even 1920x1080?

The system would need to run any windows from 7 to 10.

Edit: This is going to be used in a extended desktop environment, not replicating screens.

Thank You.

Comment: I'm not sure your card can handle 12 monitors since I can't find it on AMD's page [link](http://support.amd.com/en-us/search/faq/151)
Do you have passive or active hub ?

Answer (score 0):

If all the monitors are going to be showing the same thing, then a powered video splitter will do the job. For example, Monoprice has a 16-way VGA splitter that handles up to 1920x1440 resolution.

Comment: I was hoping to have an extended desktop between all of the 12 screens